# How can I build an insert on a desk that adjusts the height of a sewing machine?

Tags: installation, product-recommendation, woodworking

I'd like to take my executive desk ( now sewing table) and cut out a piece of it to use as a support for my sewing machine. I want the sewing machine support able to lower the machine to table height, which would enable me to have everything level and I'd be able to sew faster. I'd like it to be mechanical and not air powered. Support needs to be able to swing back up to table height when machine is not in use and must be able to lock in place.

All ideas and links appreciated

Comment: Essentially, you want to be able to sink the sewing machine in the table so that the working surface is level with the desk top, and still be able to use the desk without the machine in place I.E. you want to replace the cut out?  Is that a correct summary?

Comment: yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

My sister has a working surface for this purpose as well. Except there isn't a mechanical swivel to raise and lower it.

There is simply a drop in the desk where the machine fits. Like a small cubby, lowered from the surface. If you were to search for "sewing desk" I'm sure this is what you'd see.

Then, when she isn't sewing, a piece of glass fits into a shallow rim around this hole to make the work surface completely flat.

Consider this log at IKEA Hackers: 
http://www.ikeahackers.net/2012/07/melltorp-to-sewing-desk.html

A simple cut-out, except that the surface piece is removable.

Comment: That's along the same lines that I was thinking about.  If you carefully cut the surface, (which is nearly impossible) the removed piece could drop back in over some stops screwed in from underneath.  But I do like the glass idea.

Answer (score 0):

My 1930s era Singer dewing desk has a straightforward system for this. There is a hinge at the back of the machine, and a hinged section at the front of the sewing machine. The front section prevents the sewing machine from swinging into the desk when in normal use.

To retract the sewing machine, you tilt the sewing machine *up* slightly, and pull up the front section. This allows the machine to swing down into the desk. Then you lower the front section. A small insert covers the hole left behind, and you have a flat surface.

It basically requires four hinges and some knowledge of geometry, though I imagine it might be tricky to get the angles right.